# How to customize what happen in fit method in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm studing how to customize what happen in fit method with tensorflow 2.0 and I'm following this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit, but I noticed some difference in code at previous link; in particular it shown first this way to train model:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
           y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
           # Compute the loss value
           # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
           loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)
           print(loss)
```

and after this one:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute our own loss
            loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)
            print(loss.shape)
```

As you can see the difference is in the computation of loss function: in the first block they use a compiled loss function, whereas in the second block loss is computed with `mean_squared_error` function.
My doubts arise when I check the shape of the loss: in first case it is a scalar like this: `(tf.Tensor(0.21193008, shape=(), dtype=float32)` while in the second the print statement give me a tensor of shape `(32,)`.
My idea it is that in second case the mean over batch isn't computed and I don't know why.
I solved using the `tf.reduce_mean` but I'm not sure if it is correct. However the loss should be a scalar and therefore I don't understand how the second mode works without `tf.reduce_mean` and if the usage of this statement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

according to keras documentation

https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/#meansquarederror-function

`keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)`

this calculate loss over the last dimension only and the output does indeed contain batch size dimension. only the last dimension disappear.

Comment: I know this, but I don't understand why in [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit) they use only `keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)` without reducing on batch size (reduction which occurs using the compiled loss or tf.reduce_mean). Is it an error of tensorflow page or I miss somethings?

Comment: normally you use batch gradient descent in which average of loss of whole batch is used to update weights, but you can also use stochastic gradient descent in which each samples has its own loss, that way your model will update weights based on each sample in batch.

Comment: so you are saying that the only difference between the first code block and the second one is that in the first they used the classic mini batch stochastic gradient descent and in the second one stochastic gradient descent, right?